# shell script printf meaning

Tags: bash, shell, printf

Inside a for loop (i) I have to test:

```
if [[ "${PARAMETER[$i]}" =~ $(printf "|^%s\$" "${COMMANDS[@]" | cut -c 2-)]]; then....
```

And my doubt is in the printf part.
Sorry if it is not well explained.

Comment: the printf-part together with a command-execution and a pipe produces a formatted string consisting of the the content of the array COMMANDS that is compared to an item in an array PARAMETERS. Run the `printf` part separately in a shell to see what it does. What part do you have doubts about?

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX printf function works almost like its C counterpart. Here, the `%s` is replaced with whatever `"${COMMANDS[@]"` expands to. The result has a `|^` prepended, and a `$` appended.

If `"${COMMANDS[@]"` expands to multiple tokens, the result is the concatenation of all such strings.

Note: did you forget a blank before the `]]`?